# PopPage with returning parameters with Onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

I have two pages: **page1.html** has a button that opens **page2.html** with `pushPage('page2.html')`. Then I would like to have a selectable parameter (I'm using radio buttons) to be returned to **page1.html**, so I use `$scope.appNavigator.popPage({myParam: myValue})`, but at the controller of **page1.html** there're no params.
I expected to find `myParam` with:

```
var page = $scope.accidentInvestigationNavigator.getCurrentPage();
$scope.myParam = page.options.myParam;
```

Is it possible to send parameters to the previous page with `popPage()`?... if not, how could I return with a parameter?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Tag is "onsen-ui", as per I'm using Onsen UI. In its guide, at onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#method-popPage, it says that Options can be sent as parameters (like pushPage). The code is already described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pushPage` creates a new page object with the custom `options` but `popPage` doesn't create nor overwrite anything, so you cannot pass custom `options` backwards. This is not a bug, it is just designed like that right now.

There are many ways to share information between controllers in AngularJS: services, parent controllers, event broadcast...

I have made an example with 3 different approaches here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/XbvzKJ

I think the most interesting way is to use Onsen's `prepop` event to share information when you do a `popPage`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Fran!... I've used a service as you recommended, with `ons-prepop`  at navigator to fire a `$scope.$broadcast('update')` to refresh the value at `page1.html`.

Comment: With 2.0 is there anyway to pass information using straight Javascript?  I was thinking of just using a global variable and using the pre and post events to update my items.  Would this work?

Comment: @Munsterlander Yes, you can use navigator's `prepop` or page's `hide`/ `destroy` to save data of the current page or update the view of the previous page. If you need it you can also use page's `show` event (of the previous page) to update the view if you didn't do it directly in the other events. 'prepop' event contains leavePage and enterPage objects so perhaps it's easier.